# Evaluating If condition in Jmeter based on values in CSV

Tags: csv, if-statement, jmeter, conditional-statements

Having massive problems with something that should be simple, due to my lack of understanding of jmeter.

I have a test consisting of:

```
CSV Data Set config
Http Request
If controller(containing Json Path extractor and an assertion)
```

I only want the contents of the If statement to execute if a particular variable in the CSV is set to 'Y'.

Variable name in CSV = Check_For_Selector
The condition I've placed on the IF is `"${Check_For_Selector}"="Y"`

This doesn't work and I can't work out why.

Please note that I am using Jmeter 2.13 (forced to use this rather than 3.1).

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dmitri mentioned, you have to use `==` instead of `=` operator for comparison.

---

If still NOT working, please check below:

You should NOT keep `Post-Processors and Assertions` (Also, `Pre-processors`) without any enclosing Sampler in its scope. They won't be executed if there is NO sampler in their scope.

As you kept, `JSON Path Extractor & Assertion` inside an `If Controller`, where their scope is now, only limited to the Controller, they are NOT aware of the Sampler (`HTTP Request`, outside the `If Controller`), `JMeter` won't execute them.

Solution:

Keep `HTTP Request` inside `If Controller` **Or** Keep `JSON Path Extractor & Assertion` as a child of `HTTP request`.

References:

1. [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative way of executing the JSON Path Extractor and Assertion, ONLY if the value in the csv is correct?

Comment: There is NO alternative as per my knowledge. The rule is that you keep pre & post processors and Assertions within the scope of a sampler. you must abide by the scoping rules that are defined.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I think the main problem is that it's a pretty complex record I'm testing and doesn't lend itself well to testing in Jmeter. That being said, I have now successfully reconfigured my script to eliminate the excess log warnings I was getting using a set of 'if' statements. It ain't pretty, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you need to use `==` operator to [compare two strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) like

```
"${Check_For_Selector}"=="Y"
```

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) for more details on how to execute JMeter samplers conditionally with the help of the [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

Comment: I've looking at that article and it makes little sense to me. I've tried the evaluation as you suggested and it fails to execute the contents of the If statement.

Comment: The above expression should work assuming your `${Check_For_Selector}` variable equals `Y`. If Controller is able to execute **only sampler** so you need to have a sampler under the If Controller.
1. Check contents of *jmeter.log* file. 2. Check `${Check_For_Selector}` variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination.